# make a difference between pcap files

Tags: diff, pcap

I have two pcap files and I want to make the difference between them. And store the difference in another pcap file.

I tried diff command but it's not suitable with the binary files and I used also the pcap_diff tool but the result is inconsistent I mean pcap1 size - pcap2 size # diff pcap size.

Any help please?

Comment: It is not clear for me what this "diff" should contain. Packets from pcap 1 which are not in pcap 2? What exactly is a different packet - only payload or also timestamp, port, ... ?

Comment: Not only payload. All differences between both files. Diff should contains packets which are in pcap file 1 and not in pcap file 2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wireshark can do this:

https://documentation.help/Wireshark/ChStatCompareCaptureFiles.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1193766)